# Django / Python how to get the full request header?

Tags: python, django, http-headers, httprequest

I've been looking over what I can find about this and found something about denying access to specific user-agents but couldn't find how I can actually get the full request header. I am trying to make a customized analytics app so would like access to the full headers.. any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the headers are available in `request.META`. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#attributes).